# ForwardingX11 Issue, XAUTH and Display setting

Tags: 18.04, ssh, x11-forwarding

I've been trying to get ssh with gui using ForwardingX11 in the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file on Ubuntu 18.04 but every guide I try tells me the same thing change the ForwardingX11 to yes and then restart the ssh session using -X command after making sure xauth is installed.

I made the changes to my config (below) verify I have xauth, and echo out my $DISPLAY and $XAUTHORIZATION to find both are blank.  I assume the $XAUTHORIZATION variable being blank is why I cannot see the GUI (firefox being my test case) even after I export DISPLAY="127.0.0.1:0.0" so my question is if the XAUTHORIZATION variable is what I am missing, how to get both variables to automatically populate on a restart and what are the proper values for doing so?

```
Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
   ForwardX11 yes
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Try using the /etc/ssh sshd_config file and X11Forwarding yes on the remote machine running the sshd.

Comment: I have seen references to X11Forwarding and I just thought it was an older version of Linux's ForwardX11 as I havent been able to find it, can you please direct me to the file for it?

Comment: The package openssh-server installs the /etc/ssh/sshd_config    The X11forwarding is towards the bottom above the PrintMotd. Not to be confused with the openssl-client package which installs the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file without any  X11Fordwarding,

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining the distinction, I went ahead and made that change, also turning the on the DisplayOffset and the UseLocalhost and restarted the sshd but its still making me set the display, and not working after I export "127.0.0.1:10.1" to it.

Comment: My FordwardX11 I left commented out, and get DISPLAY=localhost:10.0 automatically set up.  Don't know what/where you found UseLocalhost, Nothing to manually set up after ssh -X mymachine, and I can run gnome-terminal and it pops up on my screen from the remote (with the localhost:10.0 display value already set).